# WebView scrolling doesn't work in WindowManager

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-windowmanager

Code snippet:

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
       WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
       WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
       WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
       PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

windowManager.addView(webView, params);
```

It works fine: browser displays, links clicking works, but web page scrolling doesn't work.

What could be the reason?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following Zoom Control properties should work.

`WebSettings l_webviewSetting   = webview.getSettings();
            l_webviewSetting.setAllowFileAccess(true);
            l_webviewSetting.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
            l_webviewSetting.setBlockNetworkImage(false);
            l_webviewSetting.setBlockNetworkLoads(false);
            l_webviewSetting.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            l_webviewSetting.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            l_webviewSetting.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
            l_webviewSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            l_webviewSetting.setUseWideViewPort(true);
            l_webviewSetting.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); 
            l_webviewSetting.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
            l_webviewSetting.getBuiltInZoomControls();`